# How to retrieve a key from the Map<String,List<String>> based on its value (an element of a list)?

Tags: groovy

I have a map looking like this:

```
def myMap = [
    'Key1': ['nameOfApp', 'nameOfApp2', 'nameOfApp3'],
    'Key5': ['nameOfApp4'],
    'Key2': ['nameOfApp5'],
    'Key3': ['xxx', 'yyy'],
    'Key4': ['aaa', 'vvv']
]
```

How can I find the KEY by providing a VALUE (which is a simple String value) ? I've tried lots of things but I'm blocked with the fact that values are lists...

As an example, if I provide `nameOfApp2`, I expect to get the key `Key1`. What's the easiest way to achieve it with Groovy?

Comment: Boggles the mind why anyone would design a map and look up something by “value” why don’t you invert the map?

Comment: The fact is that I can't update this part of the code because it's not on my scope. I'm using this map via Jenkins External Library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find` method with a predicate like `expectedValue in it.value`. Check the following example:

```
def myMap = [
    'Key1': ['nameOfApp', 'nameOfApp2', 'nameOfApp3'],
    'Key5': ['nameOfApp4'],
    'Key2': ['nameOfApp5'],
    'Key3': ['xxx', 'yyy'],
    'Key4': ['aaa', 'vvv']
]

def expectedValue = 'nameOfApp2'

def key = myMap.find { expectedValue in it.value }?.key

assert key == 'Key1'
```

The variable `it` inside the predicate closure represents each `Map.Entry<String. List<String>>` from the input map, so you can check if the expected value is a part of `it.value` list. And the last part uses `?.key` null safe operator to get the value of the key, just in case expected value is not present in any list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well. I was really close but my knowledges about Groovy are low. Thanks again :)